# Twitter Bootstrap SASS Customise

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I would like to customise Twitter Bootstrap using SASS. I have all my SASS files in my project. I was thinking that it would be a good idea to "override" all classes I use in html by using @extend of the really same class from Bootstrap.

This would give me the ability to upgrade the Bootstrap without warring if any class name has changed. All I can even change used classes quite easily later.

My custom Sass:

```
...
@import "bootstrap/buttons";

.btn {
  @extend .btn;
}
...
```

The problem here is that the import put everything what is in that file to final css. I have the question if I should customise the class namespace like this way or if it is not a good idea and I should customise the framework just using the variables and further class customisation?

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 0):

Overhead won't be too big and if you keep imports before your "dependency injection" it should be all ok.  But i don't know how useful it is in a long run. If they change class name then the properties also change and JS  works with the native classes. Also it might have some potential problems with the override priority.